# JSON format with index error

Tags: json

Error: Parse error on line 1:
{"Index":{"_id":1}}
{   "altitde": 11887.1,
"callsign": "ABX2040 ",
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Comment: Put your code in the question or at least one valid json array for it to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of text: {"Index":{"_id":1}} is a complete JSON object. After the last "}" your parser is expecting the end of the file, but you are adding a new object, starting with a new "{"

Check http://www.json.org/ to see how correct JSON must be conformed

Comment: Thanks !! I view it with Notpad++ I'll Chang the /n with EOF

Comment: Brado I tried to add the EOF via the Notpad++ (I tried CTR+Z) but fail Itry to prepare the file for ES

Comment: The problem is that your text is not valid JSON, you cannot create a JSON object { something } { something2 }, those are two separate objects, you can create them as an array [{something}, {something2}] or as two separate objects, but you cannot create a single object with that syntax